# Ways to provide content for other websites?

Tags: javascript, iframe, single-page-application

I'm arguing which is the best way to provide content for other websites/web-applications.

The basic idea is to provide a series of articles, that can be bought and embedded on the buyers website.

I already made a REST endpoint which will provide the data as JSON, allowed CORS (Cross origin resource sharing) for the buyers domain and made a simple SPA that gets the data and outputs it in a nice way. The further idea is to forward the SPA to the buyer for him to embed on the desired url via iframe.

Now I'm not sure if there are better ways to do this. What are your thoughts / experiences on this?

The solution:
 - should be easy to embed into CMS Systems
 - should allow basic customization (colors, layout)

Thanks, Marc

Comment: Basically iFrames do that <iframe src="/yoursiteurl" width="100%" height="300">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

Comment: Yes, but I don't have any access control in an iframe, no?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can give a url and a "token" to be used in the iFrame. Then in your API /GET check for the token and then just `res.redirect(<URL for your SPA>);` in case token is correct.